# How do I make sure a relative position div expands to contain all the absolute position divs with in it?

Tags: html, css

say I have something like

```
<body><div id="a"><div id="b">some content</div></div>more content<body>
```

and I don't know how much height "some content" is going to be.  But I have #b styled to position: absolute and #a styled to position: relative so #b's position is relative the the top left corner of #a.  Is there some way I can make #a expand to contain #b some that "more content" gets pushed after?

thanks

Comment: #b’s position is relative to its origin position and not to #a’s position. It’s just coincidence that both positions are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing absolute with relative might get you what you want, like in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zeWzB/).

Answer (score 2):

Your example is flawed as there is no actual need to have pos:abs on div#b as by default that element would be set at the top/left of div#a.

Using css position will take its applied element outside of the normal markup flow, even if you was to use pos:rel on div#b it would only increase the height of div#a it would not take into consideration any positioning you may have also applied to it.

There is a way you could achieve what you are after, but that would rely on using JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like position relative for #b might be a better solution.

As #b  is the first element in #a it woudl naturally appear in the top left corner of #a, so position relative will position relative to the same point as position absolute.

Also, say you want to push #b down by 30px, then you set

```
#b{position:relative;top:30px;margin-bottom:30px;}
```

Content will clear the bottom of #b because position:relative leaves a block in the content flow equal to the height of #b + 30px;

Answer (score 0):

No. Absolute positioning removes elements from document flow. Their parent and sibling tags have no way of knowing that they are overlapping an absolutely positioned element or not.